# Is there any benefit to using IPv6 on my home network?

Tags: networking, tcpip, ipv6, ipv4

I know that IPv6 is the future because there is only 4 billion IPv4 address, but on a home network, you are not going to have 4 billion users. So are there any other benefits that would make IPv6 on a home network better than using IPv4?

Comment: But with IPv4 you can't give all of your kitchen appliances billions of IP addresses!

Comment: 'cause my fridge has a twitter habit and gets very very upset if it can't tweet to all the neighbor fridges...

Comment: I don't believe your fridge has any twitter habit. Fridges have strong personality and never submit to addiction whatever it's drinking, smoking or tweeting. I think you invented it and invented it inaccurately, hence the mod down.

Comment: IPv6 is stripping your privacy. You have one address for one device, so anyone can find what you do on the Internet. Unless you hide yourself. It may be faster in core networks, but to use it in your home it's just like using gold on your fridge power plug.

Comment: seriously?! you peoples!

Comment: It's not. Set  net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr=2
 net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr=2 and your devices will have addresses unrelated to their macs.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, there is not any benefit to using IPv6 at home.

Here is a relevant question: [What interesting uses for IPv6 are out there?](https://superuser.com/questions/29606/what-interesting-uses-for-ipv6-are-out-there)

Comment: Not true for all systems. Windows 7 Homegroups uses it (as mentioned in the link).

Comment: This is so true even today in 2024. When talking about IPv6, people tend to fall back to all the benefits to the society - which are all real. However to an individual, including companies, there is no benefit to going IPv6. Dual stack is twice the work to administer, with zero incremental benefit.

Answer (score 70):

Yes, there is a benefit to using IPv6 at home. The main one is education, i.e. you will gain experience at administering an IPv6 network that you can put on your resume. In about two years from now, sometime in 2011, the world will run out of IPv4 addresses and there will be a surge in demand for IPv6 networking, and that includes a demand for people experienced in administering IPv6.

Comment: ...and we're out.

Comment: Heh. Oddly enough now in 2012 a phase-out plan has begun for IPv4 it seems: http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-weil-shared-transition-space-request-15.txt

Comment: I don't think education is what he meant ;p. He surely meant technical advantages.

Comment: IPv6 was not designed to have tecnnical advantages. It was designed to  solve a fundamental problem with the total number of available addresses. At the time it was first implemented, IPv6 did have technical advantages over IPv4, but over the years people have implemented almost all of those advantages with IPv4 as well. But the fundamental issue of not enough IP addresses remains. Because of this IPv6 *WILL* be universally deployed. It is only a question of how quickly will it reach the tipping point where it becomes the default.

Comment: `sometime in 2011, the world will run out of IPv4 addresses` Now that 2015 is nigh, I wonder did the same that happened to "Peak Oil" also happen to "Peak IPv4"? (Writing from a NATted IPv4 machine)

Comment: 2015, and still most of the world is using IPV4, but hey, TWC gave me an IPV6 address and now I also have native IPv6 running across my lan! Go me :D

Comment: This answer from 2009 says so much about the urgency of IPv6.

Comment: well its 2015 now .. and the ip addresses did run out :) at least in North America (http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/07/us-exhausts-new-ipv4-addresses-waitlist-begins/)

Comment: 2015 Oct, I am still getting an IPv4 address for each of my VPS(at no extra charge).  I also run IPv4 only at home, somehow I still can browse the internet just as others.

Comment: Now is 04/2016 and I'm able to get one public IPv4 from my ISP (more for additional pay). When I ask for IPv6 support, only a few ISPs support it - that's sad.

Comment: Still waiting... (09/2017)

Comment: Hello from 2018, yep, IPv4 is still very much a thing

Comment: What most of the commenters didn't understand is that the "new" IPv4 IP addresses they are getting each time they connect are part of a pool that their ISP already bought. It's currently not possible to buy new IPs, unless you buy them from someone else. So as a consumer, you don't notice the problem directly yet, but the problem is still there.

Comment: 10 years have now passed. The solution for many of the lazier ISPs is CGNAT which allows sharing of IPv4 addresses across users.  This sucks for a few users as it makes it hard to self-host a server, but in some cases you can pay extra to get your own IPv4.

Answer (score 21):

I use it to be able to reach all my machines from outside without doing anything special.

You could also use the improved multicast support to stream data in a much more efficient way.

IPv6 also removes a checksum so you could perhaps notice a small improvement in performance, but most likely not.

I try to use IPv6 whenever possible, mostly because it's a weee bit more nerdy... :)

Comment: We've noticed the very slight improvement in performance on large file transfers internally.

Comment: what do you mean `reach all my machines from outside without doing anything special.`  do you mean that you don't need public IPs or port forwarding ? you can just access them with their private ipv6 ?  and can you access them from an ipv4 network ?

Comment: All my IPv6-adresses are public so they could be reached from every IPv6 connected device out there. My firewall is configured to only allow ssh default.
You need native IPv6 or an IPv6 tunnel since you can't reach them from an IPv4 only network.

Answer (score 8):

Windows 7 Homegroup requires IPv6

Comment: Well, it [sort of does](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/64831-homegroup-ipv6-absolutely-required.html)...

Comment: Not sure why you would say "sort of", as the link seems to state that Homegroup 'absolutely' requires IPv6 (along with some tribulations about router capabilities of passing IPv6 (and another homegroup requirement of time sync)).

Answer (score 4):

When you run a server from home running IPv6 makes it easier - no need for static NAT translation as long as double NAT or DS-Lite is not used to connect your IPv4 host because static NAT translation will no longer be possible. So **only** IPv6 will allow you to run a Server at home.

I have an IPv6 Server at home which is not always online but I use it for testing.
It took me a minute to add the DNS record at my ISP (OVH) and that's it!

Comment: "So only IPv6 will allow you to run a Server at home." - really? And routers with NAT allowing port forwarding don't count? Granted, this makes it a little more work with IPv4 to set up, but "only IPv6 will allow you to run a server at home" - hmmm.

Comment: @LarsNordin some providers are out of IPv4 addresses and it's too expensive for them to buy more, some other ISPs simply never provided public v4 addresses to their customers. They use either CGN (Carrier Grade NAT) giving a private IPv4 to the customer, or DS-Lite (public IPv6 to customer and v4 is tunneled over v6 then passes through a CGN -- there's v4 only between the PC and the router at customer premises). In both cases, you have generally no way of configuring a port forwarding...

Answer (score 3):

Well the technical benefits of ipv6 over ipv4 is that it's natively encrypted, no broadcasting - it's all either multi-cast or unicast.

It has anycast addresses to map the nearby device network topology and geocast to have regionally identifiable addressing based on where you live in the world.

It's a hierarchical based addressing as opposed to ipv4's seemingly random addressing system where the loopback address knocks out an entire class A address block, and that knocks out about more than a million addresses where as ipv6 loopback is just one address.

Another technical benefit of ipv6 over 4 is that there are smaller DNS tables and routing tables, because routing is done regionally where the first block of numbers are your continent code, then country, then ISP, then 16 bits for your network, and the last 64 would be MAC address - so this allows for more hierarchical routing and less latency, when it's used globally.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm sorry ipv4 was hierarchical hence supernetting and sub netting however massive amounts were wasted in the Class A range and there is huge loss in the internal addresses aka RFC 1918 address system

Most times NAT is needed and this wasn't always great for people

IPv6 is also hierarchical but with 128 bit address space over the 32 bit address space there is trillions of addresses to use.
Also as stated there is no broadcast so some security is there as in nodes wont respond within a subnet to give their address.
BIG plus although on a DES level of 56 bit is that each and every PACKET of IPv6 is and has inbuilt encryption which improves security immensely although dig a bit there is still security issues somewhat but much vastly better than IPv4 on the main.
NAT is not required, Encryption at the packet level built in ..IPv6 is the only way to go..just people need to get to grips with the AAAA or quad A servers system of DNS ..then once the providers move to this it should be good for all.
Personally I wish the telecoms for mobile phones would move to IPV6 for stated security reasons mentioned.
IPv4 will go...and IPv6 is established as a replacement protocol.

Comment: Your statement that IP is hierarchical is wrong. It is not. RFC 791 1.2 specifies the scope as being `The internet protocol is specifically limited in scope to provide the functions necessary to deliver a package of bits (an internet datagram) from a source to a destination over an interconnected system of networks. There are no mechanisms to augment end-to-end data reliability, flow control, sequencing, or other services commonly found in host-to-host protocols. The internet protocol can capitalize on the services of its supporting networks to provide various types and qualities of service.`

Comment: Supernetting and subnetting is a superficial categorization.  Many RFCs (1518, 1519, 1918, 6598, and others) were simply trying to break the internet up in this way because of the rapid growth of the internet and the subsequent value an individual IPv4 has when they have been depleted.  It was the parallel to Domain Name squatting;  IP allocation squatting.  IPv6 restores the spirit of the Internet Protocol that all devices become publicly addressable.  The Brave New World will see see RFCs addressing this new social problem of handling privacy and security when NAT is redundant.